# Custom wave frequency for car radio

Tags: arduino, wireless, bluetooth, radio, automotive

My car radio doesn't support Bluetooth and I am wondering how to solve this problem so I can play songs from my phone.

The first idea that came to my mind is obviously just to buy a new radio.

However, I am wondering, just for the sake of having fun with electronics, if it was possible to somehow generate radio waves in the frequency range of the car receiver so I could for example connect my phone with an Arduino (e.g. via Bluetooth) and transmit audio in a custom frequency so the car would receive it as if it were regular radio station.

Is this, in theory, possible?

Comment: Those devices are already commercially available. Search for FM transmitter.

Comment: Anything is possible in this area.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it shows lack of research.

Comment: It's also an "is it possible" question which automatically makes it off topic (they always generate ambiguous and unuseful answers). Please write a specific question

Comment: I don't agree. The answer below actually is the exact thing I needed to hear, which vindicates the type of my question. I think less unfriendly comments would be really appreciated next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... if it was possible to somehow generate radio waves in the frequency range of the car receiver, so I could for example connect my phone with Arduino (e.g. via Bluetooth) and transmit audio in a custom frequency so the car would receive it as if it were regular radio station.

Arduino will not help you here. It doesn't, on its own, do Bluetooth, audio or radio frequencies. Its processor is too small and too slow.

[image]

*Figure 1. Random Bluetooth to FM transmitter from [Light in the Box](https://www.lightinthebox.com/).*

These types of devices are readily available and usually contain a Bluetooth receiver and FM transmitter. The one pictured also features USB charging ports and a digital display of the FM channel selected and what appears to be a hands-free phone interface.